Are the new data dumps watermarked?
Are the new data dumps watermarked? I.e., can someone identify which user downloaded them?

Even if they aren't currently watermarked, it would not be hard to add a watermark in the future. Given the size of the dumps, any watermark could be made difficult to detect without some inside information. Frankly, if I were interested in ensuring public access to the data dumps in the future, I would be setting up accounts right now to get around the inevitable blocks. There will be a reputation requirement for accessing the dumps, IPs will be blocked, and the dumps will be watermarked. Otherwise this is a lot of development work for nothing.

@ColleenV I'm hoping users can share hashes here or somewhere when a new dump is released + develop a script to clean metadata.

Without knowing how they're watermarking it, that's unlikely to happen unless they aren't really serious about blocking access to it and this is just a gesture in case their lawyers need to write a threatening letter to intimidate someone. The information exchange needed to get around the watermarking is certainly not going to happen on a site the company controls.

@ColleenV Can still compare hashes to ensure file integrity. Also, no need for self-censoring, as long as we follow SE policies, which don't preclude watermark detection discussion.

That's irrelevant to whether the company will be able to identify which user downloaded a particular version of the data dump so that they can block them from future access. You can't discuss anything you want here, regardless of the rules.

@ColleenV particular version = particular hash and/or metadata. So comparing hash and cleaning metadata will take care of that.

The minute a company uses a community dump for AI instead of paying SE, whatever technique people used to bypass the restrictions on the dump will stop working. The instant the dump was put behind a link that requires an account, it was over. Nothing the community does will have any lasting effect. If you continue to participate here you're working primarily to enrich giant corporations and give them control over the information. Do you think Google's AI will help you get around SE's watermark on the data dump? Or will you get the equivalent of I'm sorry Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.?

@ColleenV The dump isn't just for AI, but other purposes too, e.g. data perennity in case SE sinks. About AI training, data is CC BY-SA anyway, so no pb aside perhaps for attribution.

The content is being used to develop the commercial solution that is going to kill the communities that created and curated it. Do you think once Google's AI has wide enough adoption that they will ever direct another question to Stack Overflow via search instead of through their AI? Are all those junior developers who will get access to it through their workplace be likely to join SO and work at earning reputation when they can just ask a chat bot or ask on Discord without dealing with all the rules here? Any contribution here makes the commercial AI they're training on your content better.

It was tolerable when everyone had access to the data and could compete. Now, any competitor's access is going to be shut down because it hurts how much money they can make from the content we donate to them. We can't win this fight by trying to get around the restrictions. The data dump isn't worth anything without the community that adds the value to it, but it will take a while for that value to decay. We're building the bypass that is going to divert traffic away from our town and starve us of people and attention.

As far as I've been able to tell, with some info from other users, no.
The download page does contain the SE site domain and the user ID, so I would suspect that SE is not only able to track the number of downloads, but who is downloading the data dumps for a given site. Based on policies, SE may also be logging information about who accesses the page, including IP address.
However, there doesn't appear to be any differences within the data dump itself that would allow anyone to tell, given two data dumps, which user downloaded which one. Based on file sizes and hashes, two dumps downloaded by two people are identical.
However, keep in mind that the download is still rolling out. Some watermarking produces a handful of variants of the file. Until we have a much larger sample size, I'm hesitant to firmly say that watermarking doesn't exist.

All you would need is a timestamp to cross reference with logs. Is every single piece of metadata for every file in the dumps you checked identical? Because an obvious watermark is easily defeated.

FYI -- The company logs every page view, and ties it to the user/account id when you are logged in.  The primary goal of the changes is absolutely to track who downloads the dump, so that the company can select who they distribute the compiled dump to.

@ColleenV We'd need different users to compare their dump hashes.

@ColleenV A small group of mods has been comparing hashes. So far, for a given site, everyone has always gotten the same hash. This means that the files are identical. But the sample size is too small to say definitively that for dozens or hundreds of downloads, all dozens or hundreds would be identical. More data points are needed.

I don't know a lot about how those hashes are calculated. Do they only account for content or do they capture all the file permissions, various timestamps (created, modified) etc? I can hide a lot of information in places y'all would not think to look for it. Also, just because it isn't watermarked right now doesn't mean it will never be watermarked.

@ColleenV That is a good question. The md5sum command only looks at file contents and not metadata. More investigation is still needed, but there's nothing different in any of the visible metadata so far. Still need a bigger sample size, though.

They might be adding it randomly, or waiting for a while and then they'll add. Sadly, even if they will say "No, we don't and won't add", it does not mean this is true. If the goal is avoiding possible suspension due to uploading the dump to external site, I'd be extra careful.

@ShadowWizard That's true. Although implementing Journeyman Geek's feature request would mitigate most issues. If SE publishes some kind of hash, we would quickly see if the hash didn't match the file or if multiple users were shown a different hash. It's also easy enough to change file metadata from .7z and .xml files - unlike other file formats, there's not a lot of metadata. Anyone wanting to distribute wouldn't have a hard time spotting or stripping data.

@ColleenV good point indeed,  luckily there are some tools to compare metadata between two files.
